# How to get properties of a class with empty constructor using Typescript in the Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, angular7

I'm trying to bind formgroup with my class dynamically. But i can not do it with "getRawValue () as MyClass", because i've the component "auto-complete" from primeng, where it has another object within.
Ex: result from from when get RawValue.

```
{
 field1: value;
 field2: value;
 autocomplete: {filed3: value, anotherfield: value}
}
```

Ex: Class to bind

```
export MyClass {
   field1: number;
   field2: string;
   field3: number;
}
```

Then i thought to get properties from "MyClass" and compare with Raw Value, but if my class doesn't has a constructor initializing the properties i can't get their names. I also don't know if this could be the better solution.
i'm using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new MyClass());`
The objective is to use in any class in my project.

Answer (score 0):

try to initialize class with empty value in constructor

```
export class MyClass {
  constructor(
     public field1: number = 0;
     public field2: string = '';
     public field3: number = 0;
  ) {}
}
```

Then you will get values

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new MyClass());
```

Comment: this way works. But i'd like to get that values without do it.
i can do it with decorators but i'll have class by class. if there's a way to do it without initialize the properties, then i'll do it generics.